# Are there any (land) hills/mountains with *peaks* below sea level?

Tags: sea-level, mountains

Related to [Are there any (land) hills/mountains with bases below sea level?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/24199/are-there-any-land-hills-mountains-with-bases-below-sea-level), are there any peaks or cliff below mean sea level which looks out onto even lower land?

According to https://elevation.maplogs.com/poi/metsoke_dragot.207681.html, Metsoke Dragot almost fits the bill but has 6 m elevation.

Even better would be a distinct peak, such as Masada:
http://openstreetmap.org/?mlat=31.316&mlon=35.354&zoom=16&layers=Y
but it's 58 m above sea level.

[image: Masada]

Comment: Does you Question apply to seamounts too?

Comment: Guess that will do, though dry land is preferred.